# both buttons trigger one script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that triggers a script on a webpage. One instance works. When I try to add a second button/script, both buttons trigger the second script only. I know (think?) it's because the var I'm defining for the buttons are not unique to their individual scripts, but every way I attempt I break the whole thing.

```
button  {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 10px;}  
button:after {
    content: " (off)";
  }  
button.on:before {
    content: "✓ ";
  }
button.on:after {
    content:" ";
}
.frac span { 
      -webkit-font-feature-settings: "frac" 1;
          font-feature-settings: "frac" 1;
}
.onum span {
      -webkit-font-feature-settings: "onum" 1;
          font-feature-settings: "onum" 1;  
}
```

Html:

```
<button name="frac" id="frac">Fractions</button>
<button name="onum" id="onum">Oldstyle Numbers</button>
```

This text is supposed change OT features when the buttons are pressed.

JS:

```
<script>    var btn = document.getElementById("frac"),
    body = document.getElementById("textA"),
    activeClass = "frac";

btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  body.classList.toggle(activeClass);
  btn.classList.toggle('on');
});  </script>

      <!-- onum -->
<script>    var btn = document.getElementById("onum"),
    body = document.getElementById("textA"),
    activeClass = "onum";

btn.addEventListener("click", function(f){
  f.preventDefault();
  body.classList.toggle(activeClass);
  btn.classList.toggle('on');
});  </script>
```

The variance between the scripts/buttons are some of the changes from different things I've done, but I've gone mostly back to the beginning so it's simpler.

Comment: Include both the scripts in one <script> tag. Rename the variables if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Now both of the buttons work (but they undo each other). So, mostly fixed. Is it possible to have both "active" at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, every variable that you declare is inherently available across the entire page. So, putting them in separate  tags will have no effect.

So essentially, your second variable *btn* is actually overwriting the first one. Rename the second variable to say, btn2.

Or, as an alternative, change the line

```
btn.classList.toggle('on')
```

to

```
this.classList.toggle('on')
```

***this*** within the click handler will always point to the current button being clicked.

Comment: Thank you, changing the var names allows both buttons to be pressed and trigger their movement. However, they undo each other. Is this part of the same problem?

Comment: @Moonhawk Did you change it to say btn2 in all the places? var btn2, btn2.addEventListener, and btn2.classList?

Comment: @Moonhawk Also rename activeClass to activeClass2 in the second script.

Comment: Yes, I changed it everywhere, as well as for the activeClass. The 2nd button will undo the 1st, the 1st cannot undo the 2nd. But, at least they both work!

Comment: If you're still facing an issue, could you please do a jsfiddle of your code and share the URL, I can try to debug it there.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is now in the CSS: one class is overwriting the other. So I'll have to find a way in the JS to make it add to a css class instead of apply a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in fewer lines of code

```js
// you create the array of buttons

let butons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("button")),
// you define the _body
    _body = document.getElementById("textA")


// for every button in the buttons array (map is an iterator)
butons.map((btn) =>{
  //you define the activeClass to be the name attribute of the button
  let activeClass = btn.getAttribute("name");
  
  // everytime you click the button
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
  /*this was in your code. I don't know why you need it
  e.preventDefault();*/
  //you toggle the activeClass & the on class
  _body.classList.toggle(activeClass);
  btn.classList.toggle("on");
  
})
})
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
button:after {
  content: " (off)";
}
button.on:before {
  content: "✓ ";
}
button.on:after {
  content: " ";
}

/* I'm using color to visualize the change */
.frac span {
  color: red;
}
.onum span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<button name="frac" id="frac">Fractions</button>
<button name="onum" id="onum">Oldstyle Numbers</button>


<p id="textA">The variance between the <span>scripts/buttons</span> are some of the changes from different things I've done, but I've gone mostly back to the beginning so it's simpler.</p>
```

Comment: Please also add an explanation for the code. Moonhawk seems to be new to Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your message @mm. You are right. I've added the explanation as comments in the code

Comment: Thank you! The comments are very helpful in figuring out what is happening, and it worked perfectly as well in getting the two buttons to work together, thank you.